# How to print PDF documents in batch mode? (using Windows Task Scheduler)

Tags: windows, batch-file, pdf, taskscheduler

I am trying to print in batch mode each of the PDF files contained in a Windows directory by writing a batch script which uses Adobe Acrobat Reader to filter them out, but I haven't succeeded in the **<'SEVERAL-OPTIONS'>** section as follows:

```
@echo off
SETLOCAL EnableDelayedExpansion
SET WRK_PATH="c:\a\b"
SET PDF_READER_PATH="c:\d\e"
...
cd !WRK_PATH!
for /F "tokens=*" %%a in ('dir /b/a-s *.pdf') do (
@echo File: %%~fa
  **<SEVERAL-OPTIONS>**
ping localhost -4 -n 10 >nul
)
```

Where **< SEVERAL-OPTIONS>** have been:

```
1 - cmd /C "c:\d\e\AcroRd32.exe" /t %%~fa printerQ
2 - start "" "C:\d\e\AcroRd32.exe" /t %%~fa printerQ
3 - start /b "" "C:\d\e\AcroRd32.exe" /t "%%~fa" "printerQ"
4 - PowerShell -NoProfile -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -Command "& 'C:\d\e\AcroRd32.exe'" ' /t c:\a\b\file1.pdf printerQ'
```

Although some of them works fine having a Windows session active, they cannot when they are scheduled as Task.

Comment: Which ones work and which ones don't?  The question in the title of your post seems to have been answered by your post.  Is the question actually something along the lines of "how to make this work in Task Scheduler"?

Comment: Yes, it's about an issue I'm having trying to print PDF files in batch mode so I've tried to make it work by scheduling the script as a task in the scheduler, but I hadn't luck. It's about a process that stores several PDFs into a Windows folder, and I need to automate their prints, so I showed an extraction of the batch script I wrote.

Comment: Which is it?  You want to print them from the batch file or you want to print them from Task Scheduler?

Comment: About the 4 ways I tried shown above, perhaps 1,2,3 works well, but I tried  around 7 in total including some PowerShell ones, and they worked well in an interactive Windows session, but neither of them work as a job in the scheduler.

Comment: If I use the ways: 2 & 3, it works fine, but interactively, it doesn't happen when scheduled as a job.  I mean that batch script can read each PDF file, then load it using Acrobat Reader & then print it out, but it is only if it's executed interactively in a Windows session, but not when it's scheduled as job, because the idea is to set it as a job.

Comment: [Edit your post](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/48468308/edit) and change the title to ask for the kind of help you're actually looking for.  Though you haven't said so explicitly, you seem to want to print those files from Task Scheduler.  Ask for help printing PDF's from task scheduler.  Can AcroRd32.exe process wild-cards?

Comment: Just `call "c:\d\e\AcroRd32.exe" /t %%~fa printerQ`, then tell us what errors you get from Task Scheduler when you run the task that launches the batch file.

Comment: No errors are shown, but it just gets frozen.

Comment: What state is the printer in?

Comment: It's online, but in order to avoid tons of wasted paper due my tests, I did create a print queue as Generic Text with a 'FILE' port, and also set the 'Keep Printed documents' to see when they are received by the print queue.  But in this case, nothing is queued when running as a job via Task Scheduler, despite it works well interactively.

Comment: Go to your Task Manager window and export the task as XML, post that in your question (indented as code!).

Comment: Does it work in Task Scheduler if you tick *Only run when user logged in*. If so then the printer is not available to you in TS. Map the printer with a different name then use it.

Comment: Hello @ACatinLove It has been set as: **'Run whether user is logged on or not"** & also **'Run with highest privileges'**, but no errors are shown in the Task History. It just do nothing, and gets like hung, then I have to stop the task manually.

Comment: @jwdonahue - XML version added to my question above.

Comment: I told you the problem you don't have access to the users print or drive mappings.

Comment: @ACatInLove the user account I used for this process has administrator role (interactively & in the Task Scheduler) so I think the printer must be available all the time for it; there're no drive mappings either in this case.

Comment: You know better.

Comment: Remove the `<Several Options>` crap from you post.  Edit your script. You only need to `call c:\d\e\AcroRd32.exe /t %%~fa printerQ`.  Get rid of any special test queues/devices.  Test the script from the command line and then try running it manually from Task Scheduler.  Check the "Last run results status" for the task in Task Scheduler, it should say something like "the operation completed successfully. (0x0)". Check the printer output tray for results.  I think you've tried so many variations you haven't got a clue what you've really been testing.

Comment: https://www.google.com.au/search?q=run+only+when+user+logged+in+printer+site:microsoft.com